# Triangle Point Picking in 3D

Tags: random, 3d, geometry

To take random uniform points inside a triangle [Triangle Point Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrianglePointPicking.html) method is used. But this is for 2D points, how can I take random points from a triangle that is defined by 3 arbitrary 3D points?

In other words, let's say I have 3 points in 3D space, and these points define a plane, how can I take random points on the plane such that my points are uniformly sampled inside the triangle that is defined by these 3 points?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: It's not clear this is obviously offtopic, but you may have better luck on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @ChristianTernus it's perfectly on topic if you are developing a cad

Comment: @FelicePollano Sure, I didn't flag it or anything, I'm just saying he may have better luck asking there.

Comment: Belongs to and got answered at Math.SE (see the only OP accepted answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the same question on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) and it is answered. Here is the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538458/triangle-point-picking-in-3d).